# How to Parse Optional or Null XML Elements & Attributes with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I am having following type of XML:

[image]

Through this XML I wish to populate following objectList.

```
List<Function> objFunctionsList = new List<Function>();
```

where Function class is as follows,

```
public class Function
{
    public String Name { get ; set; }
    public Parameter ReturnType { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    public String Library { get; set; }
    public String Signature { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Code { get; set; }
}
```

and the Parameter class is as follows,

```
public class Parameter
{
    [DefaultValue("")] 
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public String DataType { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public String OccurenceType { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that in XML some function tags have Parameters tag while some others do not. I have tried this:

```
public const string XPATH_NAME = "/Functions/Function/Name";
public const string XPATH_LIBRARY = "/Functions/Function/Library";
public const string XPATH_SIGNATURE = "/Functions/Function/Signature";
public const string XPATH_DESCRIPTION = "/Functions/Function/Description";
public const string XPATH_CODE = "/Functions/Function/Code";

List<Function> objFunctionsList = new List<Function>();

try
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(pXMLPath);

    XmlNodeList nlName = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(Constants.XPATH_NAME);
    XmlNodeList nlLibrary = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(Constants.XPATH_LIBRARY);
    XmlNodeList nlSignature = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(Constants.XPATH_SIGNATURE);
    XmlNodeList nlDescription = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(Constants.XPATH_DESCRIPTION);
    XmlNodeList nlCode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(Constants.XPATH_CODE);

    // Name, Signature, Library, element should be present in 'Function' node
    if (nlName.Count == nlLibrary.Count
        && nlName.Count == nlSignature.Count
        && nlName.Count == nlDescription.Count
        && nlName.Count == nlCode.Count)
    {
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < nlName.Count; iCount++)
        {
            Function objFunction = new Function();
            objFunction.Name = nlName[iCount].InnerText.Trim();
            objFunction.Library = nlLibrary[iCount].InnerText.Trim();
            string signature = nlSignature[iCount].InnerText;

            Parameter objReturnType = new Parameter();
            string returnType = (nlSignature[iCount].Attributes[Constants.ATRR_TYPE] == null
                ? Constants.XSNOPARAM
                : nlSignature[iCount].Attributes[Constants.ATRR_TYPE].Value);

            if (returnType.EndsWith(Constants.ASTERIK))
            {
                objReturnType.DataType = returnType.Substring(0, returnType.Length - 1);
                objReturnType.OccurenceType = Constants.OCCURENCES_ASTERISK;
            }
            else if (returnType.EndsWith(Constants.PLUS))
            {
                objReturnType.DataType = returnType.Substring(0, returnType.Length - 1);
                objReturnType.OccurenceType = Constants.OCCURENCES_PLUS;
            }
            else if (returnType.EndsWith(Constants.QUESTION_MARK))
            {
                objReturnType.DataType = returnType.Substring(0, returnType.Length - 1);
                objReturnType.OccurenceType = Constants.OCCURENCES_QUESTION;
            }
            else if (returnType.Length > 0)
            {
                objReturnType.DataType = returnType;
            }

            objFunction.ReturnType = objReturnType;

            objFunction.Parameters = new List<Parameter>();

            objFunction.Signature = signature;
            objFunction.Description = nlDescription[iCount].InnerText.Trim();
            objFunction.Code = nlCode[iCount].InnerText.Trim();

            objFunctionsList.Add(objFunction);
        }
    }
}
```

but this is XPath based code and was in use earlier when I was not having Parameters Tag in the function tag.

Comment: I have updated the code that I have tried

Comment: If a function doesn't have parameters, does that mean that its `Parameters` member should be `null`, or an empty list, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

As [the article that @NitinRastogi mentions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/05/14/working-with-optional-elements-and-attributes-in-linq-to-xml-queries.aspx) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8441685/456814) points out, you can use some convenient properties of LINQ to make it easy to work around `null` or optional values:

1. Methods that return collections, such as [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx), will return an empty
   collection (not `null`) if no results are found or they're passed empty collections as
   input:

   > If an empty collection is passed to the `Attributes` extension method, it also returns
   >   an empty collection.
2. Some LINQ mehods that return a single value, such as [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx), also have
   variants that will return a default value, such as `null`, if no object is found,
   instead of raising an exception. In the case of `First()`, its variant is
   [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx).

So in your case, since `Parameters` are optional for your `Function` objects, you can choose to either initialize them with `Parameters` equal to `null` or an empty list.

#### Case 1: Initialize with `null`

If you want to initialize them as `null`, you can do this:

```
var doc = // XDocument.Load() or XDocument.Parse() ...
var functions =
    from f in doc.Root.Elements()
    select new
    {
        // ...
        Parameters = f.Elements("parameters").Elements().Count() == 0
            ? null
            : (
                from p in f.Elements("parameters").Elements()
                select new {
                    DataType = p.Attribute("type"),
                    Name = p.Attribute("name"),
                    Occurence = p.Attribute("occurence")
              })
              .ToList()
        // ...
    };
```

#### Case 2: Initialize with list (0 or more elements)

But that results in a lot of ugly `null` checking code. A simpler approach would be to just initialize with a list that contains 0 or more elements. These LINQ and `XElement` collection methods will all return an empty collection if there are no parameters, so that the `Parameters` property on your functions will just be an empty list instead of null:

```
var doc = // XDocument.Load() or XDocument.Parse() ...
var functions =
    from f in doc.Root.Elements()
    select new
    {
        // ...
        Parameters = (
            from p in f.Elements("parameters").Elements()
            select new {
                DataType = p.Attribute("type"),
                Name = p.Attribute("name"),
                Occurence = p.Attribute("occurence")
            })
            .ToList()
        // ...
    };
```