# Creating lists from XML with optional elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am working on some XML documents and trying to parse them into Lists.
I have read the following answers and articles but, I couldn't find a way to parse optional "Values" tag and it's elements for the code below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/05/14/working-with-optional-elements-and-attributes-in-linq-to-xml-queries.aspx ,
[LINQ to XML optional element query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278215/linq-to-xml-optional-element-query) , 
[Can XML with optional elements be used with LINQ and Anonymous Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530266/can-xml-with-optional-elements-be-used-with-linq-and-anonymous-types) , 
[How to Parse Optional or Null XML Elements & Attributes with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441566/how-to-parse-optional-or-null-xml-elements-attributes-with-linq)

The code:

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
messages = (from _message in xdoc1.Element("Messages").Elements("Message")
select new Message
{
    Id = _message.Element("Id").Value,
    Alias = _message.Element("Alias").Value,
    Fields = (from _field in _message.Element("Fields").Elements("Field")
        select new Field
        {
            FieldName = _field.Element("FieldName").Value,
            StartIndex = Convert.ToInt16(_field.Element("StartIndex").Value),
            StopIndex = Convert.ToInt16(_field.Element("StopIndex").Value),
            DefaultBits = _field.Element("DefaultBits").Value,
            CalculationMethod = (CalculationMethods.Types)Enum.Parse(typeof(CalculationMethods.Types), _field.Element("CalculationMethod").Value),
            Values = (from _value in _field.Element("Values").Elements("Value")
                select new Value
                {
                    Bits = _value.Element("Bits").Value,
                    Meaning = _value.Element("Meaning").Value
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Some "Fields" has "Field"s with "FieldName", "StartIndex", "StopIndex", "DefaultBits", "CalculationMethod" and optionally "Values". How can I fix the code for optional "Values" tags in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.Value`, use the explicit conversions in `XElement`. So for example:

```
FieldName = (string) _field.Element("FieldName"),
StartIndex = (short?) _field.Element("StartIndex")
```

You'll end up with null values for absent elements, because that's what the custom conversions on `XElement` do when the operand is null (and the return type is a reference type or a nullable value type).

For `Values`, it's even easier - you just need to change `_field.Element("Values")` to `_field.Elements("Values")`:

```
Values = (from _value in _field.Elements("Values").Elements("Value")
          select new Value
          {
              Bits = _value.Element("Bits").Value,
              Meaning = _value.Element("Meaning").Value
          }).ToList()
```

That way, `_field.Elements("Values")` will return an empty sequence if there's no `Values` element.

Comment: I can't leave my current code as it is because it gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error for Values part.

Comment: @Cnqt: Ah, I thought you had `Elements("Values")` - will edit.

Comment: Can you provide a solution for this situation?

Comment: OK, thanks. It relly helped. But I'm curious; what is the difference between using "from _value in _field.Element("Values").Elements("Value")" and "from _value in _field.Elements("Values").Elements("Value")"?

Comment: @Cnqt: `Element` returns either a null reference or a reference to a single element. `Elements` never returns null - it returns a sequence of elements, which may be empty. It's therefore always safe to dereference the result, e.g. to get subelements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the conditional oprator in linq.

```
FieldName = _field.Element("FieldName")!=null?_field.Element("FieldName").Value:string.Empty;
```

Comment: It's ok with "FieldName", "StartIndex", etc. But "Values" has two sub elements under "Value"; "Bits" and "Meaning". If there is no Value in a Field, there is neither "Fields" tag nor "Field" tag.

Comment: same you can implemeted on Bits and Meaning.

Comment: You can handle the absence of Bits and Meaning like that but, how could you handle Fields and Field tag when there is none?